# Tool to automatically generate documentation on elastic index

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, documentation-generation

I have a **project on Kibana/Elastic**. I can see / manipulate the indices and see the fields and value types with `GET <index>/_mapping`.

Other members (in particular, managers) in my team do not have access to Kibana and **I need to write some documentation** for them. Basically, I need to give them a view on what's in the indices.

I find myself copy pasting and simplifying (removing some not so informative layers) the json-like output of `GET <index>/_mapping`. That's not a good process.

**Is there a tool that automates this, and ensures synchronisation between the db and the documentation?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any tool that automates this. The simplest way, IMO, would be to create a single-page webapp which connects to ES and calls

```
GET _all/_mapping?format=yaml
```

which will return something like

```
myindex:
  mappings:
    properties:
      date1:
        type: "date"
      date2:
        type: "date"
      date3:
        type: "date"
      status:
        type: "text"
        fields:
          keyword:
            type: "keyword"
            ignore_above: 256
```

which is already more readable than JSON.

---

Going one step further, you could add a multi select dropdown to filter for specific fields, i.e.:

```
GET _all/_mapping/field/name,color?format=yaml
```

which would return something along the lines of

```
online_shop:
  mappings:
    color:
      full_name: "color"
      mapping:
        color:
          type: "keyword"
    name:
      full_name: "name"
      mapping:
        name:
          type: "text"
          fields:
            keyword:
              type: "keyword"
```

Comment: Thanks. Using yaml does make things a bit better but I was looking for an more comprehensive approach/tool.